# Camel route move files from local folder to sftp folder using multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel

So I am moving the files from  a local folder to an sftp location. The files potentially could also be in order of 500,000.
I have seda for writer process where multiple writers are writing the files, but moving the files have become bottleneck. Following is my camel route currently :

```
from(props.splitFolderUri)
            .routeId('move-files')
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'file : ${exchange.getIn().headers[\'CamelFileName\']} :: moving this split file to sftp location ')
            .to(props.remoteFolderUri)
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'file : ${exchange.getIn().headers[\'CamelFileName\']} :: moved this split file to mailbox')
```

I want to make this route multi threaded so that more than one thread keeps on moving the files.
I tried using threads(10) like as follows

```
rom(props.splitFolderUri)
        .threads(10)
        .routeId('move-files')
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'file : ${exchange.getIn().headers[\'CamelFileName\']} :: moving this split file to sftp location ')
        .to(props.remoteFolderUri)
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'file : ${exchange.getIn().headers[\'CamelFileName\']} :: moved this split file to mailbox')
```

But, I have rename file operation fail. after some research i found that this is the scenario that occurs :
Here is the scenario:

```
Thread#1 retrieves file1, moves to process folder
Thread#2 retrieves same file: file1 at the same time. file1 is deleted
Thread#2 cannot find file1 in source directory, rename fails.
Thread#1 fails due to deleted file by Thread#2
```

Thus, I tried noop=true and that works but is not a good choice for me as the files in container should be retained or I have very limited memory inside container to work with. 
So, what can be the good solution regarding the same.
I am new to camel so can`t pin point exactly what might be the best way to achieving this.

UPDATE:
I tried even following way :

```
from(props.splitFolderUri)
   .to("seda:processSplitFiles")

from("seda:processSplitFiles?concurrentConsumers=10")
    .to(log...)
    .to(props.remoteFolderUri)
    ...
```

But I keep on getting following error :

```
    {"@timestamp":"2018-05-27T22:25:48.220-05:00","@version":1,"message":"Error during commit. Exchange[ID-8c85902bd64c-60121-1527477152921-0-90793]. Caused by:w [org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - Cannot rename file: GenericFile[/apps/splitFiles/spl/stressTesting.txt_3843_sc_3843_t_10000] to: GenericFile[/apps/splitFiles/spl/.camel/stressTesting.txt_3843_sc_3843_t_10000]]","logger_name":"org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOnCompletion","thread_name":"Camel (camel-1) thread #58 - seda://moveSplitFiles","level":"WARN","level_value":30000,"stack_trace":"org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot rename file: GenericFile[/apps/splitFiles/spl/stressTesting.txt_3843_sc_3843_t_10000] to: GenericFile[/apps/splitFiles/spl/.camel/stressTesting.txt_3843_sc_3843_t_10000]
 org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileProcessStrategySupport.renameFile(GenericFileProcessStrategySupport.java:115)
  org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy.commit(GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy.java:88)
   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOnCompletion.processStrategyCommit(GenericFileOnCompletion.java:127)
    org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOnCompletion.onCompletion(GenericFileOnCompletion.java:83) org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOnCompletion.onComplete(GenericFileOnCompletion.java:57)
     org.apache.camel.util.UnitOfWorkHelper.doneSynchronizations(UnitOfWorkHelper.java:104)
      org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultUnitOfWork.done(DefaultUnitOfWork.java:229)
       org.apache.camel.util.UnitOfWorkHelper.doneUow(UnitOfWorkHelper.java:65)
        org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$UnitOfWorkProcessorAdvice.after(CamelInternalProcessor.java:654)
         org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$UnitOfWorkProcessorAdvice.after(CamelInternalProcessor.java:609)
          org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$InternalCallback.done(CamelInternalProcessor.java:239)
           org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:109)
            org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
             org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.sendToConsumers(SedaConsumer.java:298)
              org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.doRun(SedaConsumer.java:207)
               org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.run(SedaConsumer.java:154)
                java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
                  ","HOSTNAME":"8c85902bd64c"}
```

Please let me know what can be done for this.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: not an expert, but learning...)

I have a very similar scenario covered by using a single thread to pick the files up and a seda-route to actually process them in parallel.

Something like this:

```
from(props.splitFolderUri)
    .to("seda:processSplitFiles");

from("seda:processSplitFiles?concurrentConsumers=10")
    .to(log...)
    .to(props.remoteFolderUri)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use camel aggregator for working in a thread safe way.
Please find below link for aggregator:

http://camel.apache.org/aggregator.html